# code to extracting a single entry from a column in a Dataframe in R, which should be a list and not a number

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I have a question in Data Camp for an R course I'm doing.

Question:
Find the 1,031st entry of the passenger_count column and save the value under the name passenger_count_1031.

I get an incorrect submission message:
"The contents of the variable passenger_count_1031 aren't correct. It is a number, while it should be a list."

The 'passenger_count' column consists of thousands of single number entries/integers, that is in a data frame 'taxis'.

I get the correct answer, but clearly, it's not what it wants. I've tried various versions.

I tried:

```
    passenger_count_1031 <- taxis["passenger_count"][1031]  (doesn't work)
    passenger_count_1031 <- taxis[passenger_count[1031]]    (doesn't work)
    passenger_count_1031 <- taxis[[passenger_count]][[1031]](doesn't work)
    passenger_count_1031 <- taxis[taxis$passenger_count][1031] (gives you the whole list on the column, not what they want)
    passenger_count_1031 <- taxis$passenger_count[[1031]] (get the same incorrect submission message)
```

this is my code:

```
    passenger_count_1031 <- taxis$passenger_count[1031]
```

I expect the answer should be just a single value, which I get:

```
    > passenger_count_1031
    [1] 1
```

It is an integer. So why is it asking for a list?

Comment: `taxis$passenger_count[1031]` should have worked I think but since it is asking for a list try `list(taxis$passenger_count[1031])`

Comment: It sounds like Data Camp is confused. There's nothing about that question that would indicate that the answer should be a list. Are you sure there's not an error elsewhere?

Comment: So I answered the question below. I personally think their wording in the question is wrong. Thanks for the replies thou!! @RonakShah

Comment: I agree completely! I figured it out eventually, my answer is below. But personally, I agree their question is wrong. Thanks for the reply @MrFlick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!!

The code is supposed to be:

```
    passenger_count_1031 <- taxis["passenger_count"][1031, ]
```

Apparently, they want you to extract rows and columns, and not a single entry. I think their wording in the question is a bit wrong.
Anyway, fixed it.